# Exercises reference in function field theory.

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, function-fields

I am currently trying to learn about algebraic function fields.
I am using as a reference Algebraic function fields and codes from Henning Stichtenoth.

This book is unfortunately rather difficult for me to read as the fist chapter lacks examples and has no exercises. I tried to search on the Internet on this topic, but it doesn't seem to be that well covered.

If someone knows any reference for exercises that would cover the basics and complement well this book, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Have you looked at *Number Theory In Function Fields* by Rosen?  As for examples, the field of rational functions of any curve is an example of a function field in one variable.  For instance, $K(x)[y]/(y^2 - (x^3 - x))$ is the function field of an elliptic curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be unfortunately a lack of literature in regards to this topic, but I have found a book that does contain exercises.

It is  *Topics in algebraic field theory* by Gabriel Salvador.